# Transform Mono<Void> in Mono<String> adding a value

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My program services offer some delete methods that return `Mono<Void>`, e.g.: `fun delete(clientId: String) : Mono<Void>`

After calling `.delete("x")` I would like to propagate the clientId downstream to do other operations:

```
userService.get(id).map{ user -> 
        userService.delete(user.id) //This returns Mono<Void>
    .map { 
        user.id //Never called!!!
    }
    .map { userId -> 
        //other calls using the propagated userId
    }
}
```

The problem is since delete returns a `Mono<Void>`, the following `.map { 
 user.id }` is never called. So how can I transform the `Mono<Void>` into a `Mono<String>` to propagate the userId?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`thenReturn`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#thenReturn-V-) operator:

```
userService.get(id)
        .flatMap { user -> userService.delete(user.id).thenReturn(user.id) }
        .flatMap { id -> //other calls using the propagated userId }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around it using hasNext that transforms it into a Boolean:

```
    @Test
    fun `should`() {
        val mono: Mono<String> = "1".toMono()
                .flatMap { id ->
                    val map = Mono.empty<Void>()
                            .hasElement()
                            .map {
                                id + "a"
                            }.map {
                                (it + "1")
                            }
                    map
                }


        mono.doOnNext {
            println(mono)
        }.subscribe()
    }
```

Comment: Be carefull, Reactor docs said that ``hasElement()`` emits and completes before the actual Mono, so if you want to make something on completion the effects could change: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#hasElement--